# How to find access element in 2D array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongoose, mean-stack

I am working on MEAN Stack web application. I am trying to use 2D array in one of my model. Here is schema of specific field:

```
alerts:  [{ name: String, time: Number}]
```

Now I am trying to access it in my UI application. Here is my approach to access and save data.

```
             if ($scope.task.NewUserAssigned){
                    if($scope.task.alerts.indexOf({name: "NewUserAssigned"}) == -1)
                        $scope.task.alerts.push({name: "NewUserAssigned", time: $scope.task.NewUserAssignedtime});
                        console.log("Checked:  NewUserAssigned");
               }}
```

But I am doing something wrong in following syntax

```
 if($scope.task.alerts.indexOf({name: "NewUserAssigned"}) == -1)
```

And this is why, I can't search the specific index. This code saves my data in database. 
**Now how can I access element in array?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a common JS questions.

Array.indexOf is not working like a query. You have to look up the specific value. More than that, with objects its tricky. indexOf with object will only work, if the object realy are the same (same reference).

So you can use  something like that:

```
var index = $scope.task.alerts.map(function(alert){
  return alert.name;
}).indexOf('NewUserAssigned');

if(index === -1){
 ....
}
```

Or just with a loop:

```
var index = -1;

for(var i = 0, alertsLen = $scope.task.alerts; i < alertsLen; i++){
  var alter = $scope.task.alerts[i];

  if(alert.name === 'NewUserAssigned'){
    index = i;
    break;
  }
} 

if(index === -1){
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately - `indexOf` doesn't work with arrays of objects (which is what you have, *not* a 2d array) - you'd have to loop and find the object:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.task.alerts.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.task.alerts[i].name == "NewUserAssigned") {
        //Found object at index: i, do something
    }
}
```

Comment: not entirely accurate explanation of indexOf since it does work when references are same

Answer (score 0):

**indexOf** function search object by reference that is why your code does not work as expected.

For searching arrays with given predicate underscorejs [find](http://underscorejs.org/#find) function is useful.